# How can I Dockerize my Symfony Application?

Tags: php, docker, symfony, webpack

Recently I started developing a website using Symfony. My goal is simply to learn, and as such I am using a variety of different dependencies and quite a few node modules.

Now I have already looked into a lot of documentation about docker and Symfony, however nothing I can find has really helped me.

The largest frameworks/techs I am using are Symfony-7, webpack (encore), twig, doctrine and bootstrap-5.3 along with as mentioned quite a few other composer-"modules" and node-modules.

In my project I have a docker-compose file.

Any help or pointers towards the right direction are massively appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

First of all run a basic php script with docker, which just prints hello world on browser page,

learn about how you can run a server inside a docker and map that server port of docker to the port of device, which is called port mapping.

then learn how you can move a php script inside docker container and then server that php script from the docker container with that server running inside docker.

Then you can replace basic php script with symphony directory (you will need to make changes to server setup)

these basic understanding will guide you to your goal of running symphony with docker

below blog will be helpful
https://medium.com/@miladev95/dockerizing-a-php-application-e3c756670336